# Oracle APEX escape -- and , characters

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a requirement to escape -- and the , character. The `apex_escape.html_attribute` function (APEX Version 20.1) does not escape these 2 characters. Is there a way to extend this function to also include -- and , characters.
Any ideas on how else I can escape these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own escape function for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION escape_hyphen( p_string IN VARCHAR2 )
    return VARCHAR2
AS BEGIN
  RETURN replace(p_string, '-', '&#45;');
END escape_hyphen;
/

Function ESCAPE_HYPHEN compiled

SELECT APEX_ESCAPE.HTML_ATTRIBUTE (
    p_string => '<span>hello world--</span>' ) from dual;

&#x3C;span&#x3E;hello&#x20;world--&#x3C;&#x2F;span&#x3E;


SELECT escape_hyphen(APEX_ESCAPE.HTML_ATTRIBUTE (
    p_string => '<span>hello world--</span>') ) from dual;

&#x3C;span&#x3E;hello&#x20;world&#45;&#45;&#x3C;&#x2F;span&#x3E;
```

Note 1: You first have to do APEX_ESCAPE.HTML_ATTRIBUTE and only then escape the additional characters, else your escaped hyphen will be double escaped.

Note 2: This just escapes any "-", so also "--" and "------". If you specifically want "-" and "--" you can pimp the function with a regular expression.